# Regarding static and final variable effect on class

Tags: java, scope

If you execute this program you will get only the `i` value but not SIB, my question is when class loading into the memory SIB should execute and should give ooutput, but here I am getting only the `i` value? Then keep one method in class test then call that method from another class then you will get output of SIB, `i` method ( keep method also as static final)

```
    class Test      
    {
    static final int i =3;  
    static
    {
        System.out.println("SIB");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("IIB");
    }
    }
    class A1
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(Test.i);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand, partly because of the formatting and partly because you're misusing terminology: "If at all i am executing the i variable by keeping final keyword" makes no sense at all. You don't *execute* a variable.

Comment: I find it difficult to fallow you, could you please rephrase your question ?

Comment: If the OP includes the the declaration and initialization of a static final field, the static blocks of code in that class do not get executed.  If final is removed from the declaration/initialization, the blocks do get executed, its a good question, just poorly worded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `static final` variable is a **compile-time constant** and its value is copied into the other class referencing it. Therefore your class `Test` won't load and no initializers will be executed. When the variable is only `static`, then the class must be loaded to read the current value and your SIB block will be executed. The IIB block will be executed only when you **instantiate** `Test` with `new Test()`.

Comment: ok. what about static final method ..?, keep static final method in Test class and call it from A1 class then we will get SIB, i , method o/p....?. this time class get load into memory how...?

Comment: The `final` modifier has no effect on static methods. It is irrelevant to this discussion.